# What is the remainder of $212^{2017}$ divided by $213$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Taken from a recent Mathletes event: What is the remainder of $212^{2017}$ divided by $213$? (Only the most basic TI calculator was allowed, so no brute force calculation)

Comment: What do you know about arithmetic modulo $213$? (Or modulo some other number?)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $212 \equiv -1 \pmod{213}$ and $(-1)^{2k+1} = -1$

Comment: OH, so $212$ has the same modulo as $-1$? So the modulo alternates between $1$ and $212$. Neat. $212$'s the final answer?

Comment: Yes. You're on the right track. modulo $n$ corresponds to the remainder you get after division by $n$. So modulo $213$ takes on values between "$0$" and $212$.
On a side note, I would highly recommend you to practice some modular arithmetic. There's a lot of interesting practice material available on internet. Have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "mod $213$" answer is best, but a more elementary observation is that

$$212^{2017} = (213-1)^{2017} = (\mbox{terms divisible by $213$ }) + 213^1(-1)^{2016} + (-1)^{2017}$$

by the binomial theorem.  So the above equals $213*N + 213 -1$ which has remainder $212$ upon division by $213.$

A second, maybe more clever, observation:

$$212^{2017}+1 = 212^{2017}+1^{2017} = (212+1)(212^{2016} - 212^{2015}+ \cdots +1)$$

so we immediately see that $212^{2017}+1$ is a multiple of $213$, and the conclusion follows.